# RegEx to remove key and certificate headers and footers

Tags: c#, regex, certificate

I need to strip out the header and footer of key and certificate files (as well as any LF found in the data). Yes, I can use String.Replace for all of the headers and footers but it can be done in one or perhaps two lines using RegEx. My problem is that I know nothing about the RegEx syntax. Can anyone tell me the search pattern to locate the headers (-----BEGIN *some variable text*-----) and replace them with empty strings? Note the footers all start with -----END.

Comment: I fear you will soon be bombarded with an impressive amount of downvotes... [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can research about it. Don't you?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate question. I didn't spot any that looked similar to what I wanted. The answer to the other question did the trick (even though I don't have "/" in my strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestRegex
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string begin = "-----BEGIN some variable text-----";
            string end = "-----END";

            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(begin, "-----BEGIN .*-----", ""));
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(end, "-----END.*", ""));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The string actually starts with "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----" followed by a host of encrypted data and then ends with "-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----". The first replace line in your answer wipes out the entire string. I guess it's replacing everything between the first found string and the last set of dashes.

Comment: Yes, it replaces the entire string. What is the result you are looking for? Do you want to remove the variable text between the ------BEGIN and ------ or keep the variable text and remove the dashes and BEGIN keyword?

Comment: The words "ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY" vary depending on the type of key or certificate you have. I wanted an expression that would remove the header and footer regardless of that text. I found the answer in the duplicate question's answers.

Comment: string intermediate = Regex.Replace(contents, "-----.*?-----", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline); Does the trick.

Comment: where "contents" is the entire contents of my key file.

Comment: Ok. You had the entire content in one string. I thought you were going through it line by line. You have found the correct solution anyway!